# How to say in German "enjoying home comforts"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you translate "At the moment I am enjoying home comforts."

Is it "Ich genieße häuslichen Komfort"?

Basically it means I'm enjoying the comfort of my home (things in a house that makes it comfortable).

Comment: I have no idea what the English phrase is supposed to mean,despite knowing all the words. Can you supplement this? It may still be out of scope due to requesting translation of an individual text however.

Comment: Same here! You should explain the meaning and context (!) of your sentence. And it is not that I weren't used to using English... but it seems "home comforts" is a specific cultural concept, perhaps from the... USA? In any case, your *Ich genieße häuslichen Komfort* is grammatically correct (but for the missing period at the end), but nobody would ever say this, and nobody really would understand what you mean. Do you mean you prefer having good furniture over having bad furniture?

Comment: Could you please add, what exactly created your doubts about your translation?

Comment: Basically it means I'm enjoying the comfort of my home (things in a house that make it comfortable)

Comment: I used google translate but wasn't sure if that was 100% accurate.

Comment: The English metaphor is usually "the comforts of home", not "home comforts".

Comment: I wonder if it is somehow similar to "Urlaub auf Balkonien". Is it used as excuse, not going into vacations, maybe because traveling is too expensive?

Comment: I rarely hear people using "the comforts of home" it's always been "home comforts" well especially in Australia.

Comment: It is a metaphor for "at the moment i am relaxing (at home)" which is what germans would say: "Ich entspanne mich gerade (zu Hause)". If you want a better direct translation use "häusliche Atmosphäre" which is also used in advertising

Answer (score 11):

With the explanation given later about sitting at home and enjoying it (i.e. it some form of ***Home sweet home***):

> Ich bin gerne zuhause.

in normal conversation, to relate a principal mindset, or

> Im Moment bin ich zuhause und lass' es mir gutgehen.

in normal conversation, to relate a special, momentary situation.

That's for everyday use, e.g. when talking to friends. In other situations, other forms to express yourself could be used. In high-register, e.g. in a wedding speach:

> Ich genieße die Annehmlichkeiten des häuslichen Lebens.

Or even more manieristic:

> Ich ergötze mich an den Segnungen der väterlichen Heimstatt.

But note that this is so overdone, it almost everywhere will be understood as parodistic, even in a wedding speach. (*Väterlich* is here for: "I inherited this place.")

As you see, it depends totally on the context where you want to say something like this.

#### Other expressions

> Ich bin zuhause und genieße die Freiheit.

This would be understood as: "I am at home - where I feel well (not much depending on how the home is equipped, but we suppose it it has sufficiently nice features), and I am not going to work, and I am happy about this."

> Eigener Herd ist Goldes wert

That's a a proverb that could be cited to express the thought of "enjoying home comforts", too.

Finally, in normal German speaking society, you can also say

> Home sweet home

and will be understood. The English proverb is known to average people even if they otherwise are not used to using English. "Home sweet home" has somehow made it to being naturalised in German.

#### Post scriptum

I see that I totally missed the most obvious answer: *Ich mach's mir zuhause gemütlich* - as below in the comment by Henning and the answer by RHa. This indeed is a very popular phrase.

Comment: This might be a chance to use a word that in my experience puzzles English speakers sometimes: "Gemütlichkeit". You could say "Im Moment mache ich es mir zuhause gemütlich."

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck   Well said! - I would have included this in the answer, but I see that RHa published an own answer with that, so I leave it.

Answer (score 10):

Other possible translations:

> Ich mache es mir gerade zu Hause bequem.
>
> Ich mache es mir gerade zu Hause gemütlich.